# Connect Yubikey key to GitHub

Tags: github, yubikey

I recently purchased a YubiKey for two-factor authentication, but I don't know how to connect it to GitHub.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Step 1: Enable *Two-factor authentification* on your GitHub account

1. Sign in to your GitHub account.
2. Click your profile picture in the top right of the screen.
3. Select **Settings**
4. In the left panel, select **Security**
5. Click **Enable two-factor authentification**
6. Choose the method of you want to receive one-time passwords, **Set up by using an app** or **Set up using SMS**

### Step 2: Adding your Yubikey for two-factor authentification

1. Sign in to your GitHub account.
2. Click your profile picture in the top right of the screen.
3. Select **Settings**
4. In the left panel, select **Security**
5. To the right of "Security keys", click **Add.**
6. Insert your YubiKey into USB port.
7. In the Security keys section, click **Register new device.**
8. Type a nickname for your YubiKey, then click **Add.**
9. Wait your YubiKey to begin flashing, then tap the gold button or edge.

**For more information: https://yubikey.com.ua/en/using-yubikey-with-github/**

Comment: The tuto work with Ubuntu latest ?

Comment: Your OS does not affect this tutorial because all manipulations are done on your GitHub account. But if your operating system does not detect your key, you can go to the YubiKey website: https://yubico.com

But you must use the latest version of **Google Chrome**, **Mozilla Firefox**, **Opera** or **Microsoft Edge**.